# Where to store IV that is needed for decryption in Android app?

Tags: c#, android, aes, keystore, initialization-vector

Where should I store the IV (byte array) needed for AES decryption in my Android app? I've tried converting it to a string in Base64 and saving it to shared preferences, but kept getting a bad padding exception. I tried to change the padding, but it didn't work.

I also saved the IV (byte array) to the keystore's provider and that worked, but while debugging in Visual Studio for Mac, the provider's content (in this case the IV) gets erased every time I run the app. The provider is still there but nothing is saved in the provider. Android's documentation says that "Each provider... is configured in each runtime it is installed in." Will this be an issue once the app is installed on an actual device?

I am coding in c# in Visual Studio for Mac.

**Edit**

this is my code using Base64 encoding:

string ivString = Base64.EncodeToString(ivByteArray, Base64Flags.Default);

byte[] decodedIV = Base64.Decode(ivString, Base64Flags.Default);

when I print out the original byte array and the decoded byte array, they are exactly the same but I keep getting a bad padding exception

I am using AES, CBC, and EncryptionPaddingPkcs7

Comment: I have used `SharedPreferences` for storing `IV` in `Base64` encoding and it worked correctly. You are probably making mistake somewhere. Even though not in c#, in Java.

Comment: Storing the IV "somewhere" is just making things more complicated, just prepend it to the encrypted text, it does not need to be secret.

Comment: The code to store the IV does not seem to be the problem. Show your encryption and decryption code and how you store the AES key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried converting it to a string in Base64 and saving it to shared preferences, but kept getting a bad padding exception.

Storing IV in SharedPreferences should work. You probably got a base64 encoding issue.

> I also saved the IV (byte array) to the keystore's provider and that worked, but while debugging in Visual Studio for Mac, the provider's content (in this case the IV) gets erased every time I run the app.

A `java.security.Provider` it is not the place to store a bytearray. Do you mean [Android Keystore System](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html) or other implementation of [java.security.KeyStore](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html). Please be specific

> Where to store IV that is needed for decryption in Android app?

Just prepend the initialiation vector to the ciphertext

```
 [IV][ciphertext]
```

Comment: @Harminder Kaur As answered: "Just prepend the initialiation vector to the ciphertext," The IV does not need to be secret, just unique such as random value.

Comment: @HarminderKaur If you are encryption passwords that is not secure. **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Also just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions that consume about 100ms of CPU time. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.